# How to convert these for loops to list comprehensions and map functions

Tags: python

I want to improve the performance of my code but having trouble getting it to work. How would I change the following for loops to list comprehensions?

```
def normalise_data(data): # returns unique rows 
    dim_data = []
    for row in data: # data is a list of lists
        if row not in dim_data:
            dim_data.append(row)
    return dim_data

def convert_dates(data):
    if self.date_col: # date_col is part of constructor argument (can be None hence if statement here)
        for row in data:
            for index in self.date_col:
                if len(row[index]) > 10:
                    row[index] = row[index][:-5].replace('T',' ')
                    row[index] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[index], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                else:
                    row[index] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[index], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return data

for file in files:
    csv_file = read_file(file) # read_file function opens, reads and converts csv data to a nested list
    csv_headers = ', '.join(csv_file[0])
    csv_data = csv_file[1:]
    csv_data = normalise_data(csv_data)
    csv_data = convert_dates(csv_data)
```

I've heard list comprehensions and map functions are faster than for loops however I've not been able to successfully convert my for loops to that.

Comment: don't. those list comprehensions would be a mess. rather vectorize it.

Comment: "I've heard list comprehensions and map functions are faster than for loops" not really, no. List comprehensions are sometimes marginally faster, but these constructs should be used for improving code organization and readability, not for performance

Comment: Much of what you're trying to do could be simply done in a few lines with [pandas](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-pandas-tutorial-complete-introduction-for-beginners/) which would help vectorize it like @mcsoini said.

Edit: Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: [Numba speeds up Python Loops](https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-you-can-get-some-free-speed-on-your-python-code-with-numba-89fdc8249ef3)

Answer (score 1):

The `normalize_data` function is just removing duplicates. You can use a common unique everseen algorithm using a `set`.

```
def normalise_data(data):
    seen = set(); seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in data if not (x in seen or seen_add(tuple(x)))]
```

As for the other loop I'm unsure what you're iterating over but using `itertools.product` may be a better alternative than a nested loop here.

```
def convert_dates(data):
    if self.date_col: # date_col is part of constructor argument (can be None hence if statement here)
        for row, index in itertools.product(data, self.date_col):
            if len(row[index]) > 10:
                data[index] = row[index][:-5].replace('T',' ')
                data[index] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[index], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            else:
                data[index] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[index], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return data
```

Comment: Post mentions data is "data is a list of lists".  Doesn't that mean that elements of data are lists so they can't be dictionary keys?

Answer (score 0):

**Refactoring**

- Function **normalise_data** speed up by using set and map
- Function **convert_dates**--speed up by use of Numba which uses JIT
  to speed up loops (only requires the JIT code decorator)

**Code**

```
from numba import jit

def normalise_data(data):
  """ Using set to find unique items
      Map elements first two tuples, so we can create a set of elements """
  #return list(dict.fromkeys(data))
  return list(map(list, (set(map(tuple, lst)))))

@jit
def convert_dates(data):
    if self.date_col: # date_col is part of constructor argument (can be None hence if statement here)
        for row in data:
            for index in self.date_col:
                if len(row[index]) > 10:
                    row[index] = row[index][:-5].replace('T',' ')
                    row[index] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[index], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                else:
                    row[index] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[index], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return data

for file in files:
    csv_file = read_file(file) # read_file function opens, reads and converts csv data to a nested list
    csv_headers = ', '.join(csv_file[0])
    csv_data = csv_file[1:]
    csv_data = normalise_data(csv_data)
    csv_data = convert_dates(csv_data)
```